# inject config programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php, base-url, core-config-data

Is there a way to inject custom core_config_data into magento?

I would like to set `web/secure/base_url`, `web/unsecure/base_url` and some others config dynamic and depending on the host.

I tried to remove the `core_config_data` values from the database and inject a new XML node: `default/web/secure/base_url` to the config in the index.php.
But I think before the `Mage::run()` it's to early and after the `Mage::run()` it's to late to change the config.

Does someone tried something familiar or is there already a cool solution?

Answer (score 3):

in app/etc/local.xml for each host put the following:

```
   <stores>
        <default>
            <web>
                <unsecure>
                    <base_url>http://host_name.com/</base_url>
                </unsecure>
                <secure>
                    <base_url>http://host_name.com/</base_url>
                </secure>
            </web>
        </default>
    </stores>
```

Comment: Dann, you're right. I forgot that this is possible. Thank you very much. This would be a perfect solution without php

Comment: no problem please accept

Comment: I thought about this solution. I fact with your solution it's only possible to set the config based on the website or store and NOT by the actual host.